# Randomly generate a weighted number in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I am trying to generate an random weighted number for an arbitrary cell in a Sudoku

```
90% of the time, it should generate Nothing
10% of the time, it should generate a random value between 1 and 9
```

This is what I have came up with so far  (it does not compile)

```
-- cell generates an arbitrary cell in a Sudoku
-- cell :: Gen (Maybe Int)


cell = case x of 1 -> return (Just y); _ -> return Nothing
        where std = mkStdGen(100)
              (x, a) = randomR(1, 10) std
              (y, a')= randomR(1, 9) std
```

Any help in getting it to compile, or by pointing me towards a better approach is much appreciated

---

Using Quickcheck this is how I did it:

```
-- cell generates an arbitrary cell in a Sudoku
cell :: Gen (Maybe Int)
cell = frequency [(9, return Nothing), 
               (1, do r <- choose (1,9); return (Just r))]        

-- an instance for generating Arbitrary Sudokus
instance Arbitrary Sudoku where
  arbitrary =
    do rows <- sequence [ sequence [ cell | j <- [1..9] ] | i <- [1..9] ]
       return (Sudoku rows)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using QuickCheck, you certainly don't want a `cell` to a pure value - `randomR (0,100) (mkStdGen 43434343)` is not random whatsoever, so it will be useless to you for testing.

Since you are using QuickCheck, you need to use QuickCheck functions. You cannot easily use `System.Random` nor should you. Simply use the (quite powerful) QuickCheck API, which has a function `choose :: Random a => (a,a) -> Gen a`, which picks a random number in the range, and a function `frequency :: [(Int, Gen a)] -> Gen a` which selects a random generator, based on its weight, ie the likelihood, and returns that generator. You can write `cell` as:

```
cell :: Gen (Maybe Int)
cell = frequency 
  [ (1, Just `fmap` choose (1,9))
  , (9, return Nothing) 
  ]
```

Then, for example, if you define your Sudoku board as `data Sudoku = Sudoku [[Maybe Int]]`, you can easily write an `Arbitrary` instance for it using `cell`:

```
import Control.Monad (replicateM)

instance Arbitrary Sudoku where 
  arbitrary = Sudoku `fmap` replicateM 9 (replicateM 9 cell)
```

Comment: I realized that quickcheck had a number of functions that made it a lot easier to do what I wanted to, at first I didnt realise it had its own functions for achieving randomness.

I edited the post to include how I did it, I did not use fmap and replicateM (i dont really know what they do), but I think our solutions are very similar

Comment: Our solutions are identical! (In the sense that you essentially just inlined the definitions of `fmap` and `replicateM`.) For future reference, `fmap` is like `map` but for other datatypes - in this case, it is use with the type `(a -> b) -> (Gen a -> Gen b)` - so basically it just 'lifts' a function to modify a value *inside* a `Gen`, and you do the exact same, but with `do` notation. And `replicateM n` is just `sequence . replicate n` - you replace the replicate with a list comprehension and then call `sequence`, achieving an identical effect.